# How to remember active tab using the current version of jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When my page refreshes I want to be able to get back to the tab the user was last on.  The current api documentation does not mention cookies anymore to do the tab selection anymore.  How would one go about doing this now with cookies now?

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#tabs").tabs();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
                <p>Tab 1 text</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">
                <p>Tab 2 text</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-3">
                <p>Tab 3 text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have several options. You can use cookies, sessions, the history api, local storage or session storage. All of these are solutions, generally used injunction with each other for fallback.

Comment: You can also use the hash which would allow deep linking into tabs.

Comment: See my answer in related question http://stackoverflow.com/a/18576231/268351

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So here is what I came up with.  When a user activates a tab a cookie will be set with the index of the selected tab.  When the tab widget is initialized the value is read from the cookie and loaded.  This seems to be working even if the cookie does not exist and only loads the tab the user last selected when a cookie exists.

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function( event, ui ) {
        $.cookie("tabs_selected", $("#tabs").tabs("option","active"));
    },
    active: $("#tabs").tabs({ active: $.cookie("tabs_selected") })
});
```

Comment: jQuery UI 1.9 and no working..... how sure you are that it is correct?

Comment: it is not working for me too

Comment: Make sure you have the jquery cookie plugin added.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ cookie: { expires: 30} });
```

Comment: Thanks but the cookie option was deprecated as of jQuery UI 1.9

Answer (score 0):

you can edit jquery-ui.js file

1. open the file
2. search for `this.anchors.bind("click.tabs",function(){return!1})}`
3. replace with `this.anchors.bind("click.tabs",function(){})}`

refresh your page 
and it's all right