# Keep selected tab on PageReload

Tags: jquery

This is my code sample

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Customer Application Form ::Corporate</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tabcontent.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabcontent.js"></script>
<script>
     // store the currently selected tab in the hash value
    $("ul.tabs > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function (e) {
        var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
        window.location.hash = id;
    });

    // on load of the page: switch to the currently selected tab
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('#ulid a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="Form1" runat="server" class="register">
<div id="tabs">
<ul id="ulid" class="tabs">
    <li> 
        <a href="#Tab1" id="One" class="dtls">Text A</a>
    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#Tab2" id="Two" class="dtls">Text B</a>
    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#Tab3" id="Three" class="dtls">Text C</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<p>&nbsp</p>

<div id="Tab1">Content AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
<div id="Tab2">Content BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</div>
<div id="Tab3">Content CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</div>
</div>  

 <a href="javascript:location.reload();">
 <h1>Reload page</h1></a>
</form>
```

If I selected any tab inside page and after reload the page the Tab1 is selected. I want to remain on that tab which is selected (eg Tab4) whether default Tab1 is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery cookies plugin for that

```
$('#tabID').tabs({ cookie: { expires: 999, name: "HomepageA" }, cache: false, collapsible: true });
```

more info you can check here [Remember which tab was active after refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299435/remember-which-tab-was-active-after-refresh)

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">        $.uiBackCompat = false;</script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And the js:

```
     $("#divTabs").tabs({
        activate: function (event, ui) {
            window.location.hash = 'tab=' + $(this).tabs('option', 'active');
        },
        create: function () {
            if (window.location.hash) {
                var active = parseInt(window.location.hash.replace('#tab=', ''));
                $(this).tabs("option", "active", active);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Rudy: not resilved my problem

Comment: Are you using the latest jQuery and jQuery UI? Ar you already setting something else in the hash?

Comment: latest jquey i am using.

Comment: It should work with the new version of `jQuery UI`. If it is the latest version, you can try adding this after jQuery has loaded, but before jQuery UI `<script type="text/javascript"> $.uiBackCompat = false; /script>`