# Remember jquery tabs selected tab after redirected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have couple of buttons in `Tab2`. Those buttons redirect the `page1` to `Page2`. In `Page2` I have link which redirect back to `Page1`. But when `Page1` loads it showing `tab1`, not `tab2`. So how to remember `tab2` here.

```
    var selected_tab = 1;
        $(function () {

            var handleSelect = function(e, tab) {

                var index = tab.newTab.index()
                if (index == 1) {
                    $("#divRightPanel").hide();
                    $("#divtabs").width("100%");
                } else {
                    $("#divRightPanel").show();
                    $("#divtabs").width("49%");
                }
            },
              tabOpts = {
                  beforeActivate : handleSelect
              };
            $("#tabs").tabs({ beforeActivate: handleSelect});

            $("form").submit(function () {
                $("[id$=selected_tab]").val(selected_tab);
            });
});
```

Edit: As post [jquery ui tabs no longer supporting cookie? now what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313270/jquery-ui-tabs-no-longer-supporting-cookie-now-what/14313315#14313315)
It is remembering fine. But `handleSelect` is not firing where I am hiding div inside.  any suggestions?

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
     beforeActivate: handleSelect,
    active   : $.cookie('activetab'),
    activate : function( event, ui ){
        $.cookie( 'activetab', ui.newTab.index(),{
            expires : 10
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Near-duplicate of [Remember which tab was active after refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299435/remember-which-tab-was-active-after-refresh)

Comment: @nunzabar Please updated posted.

Comment: Thanks; I didn't realize the cookie option was deprecated. Looks like you solved that and now have a different problem. Maybe it should be a new question.