# How to activate particular tab using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 tabs with 3 different ids.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });

  $("#links > a").click(function() {
    var link = $(this).attr('href').substr(-1,1);
    console.log(link);
    $('#tabs').tabs({active: link});
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="tabs"><ul>
  <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li></ul>
</div>

<div id="tabs-1">
  <p>Content 1</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
  <p>Content 2</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
  <p>Content 3</p>
</div>
```

How can i activate "tab-2" while page reload using jQuery?

**Note : without place "active" in class.**

The above code activating first tab. Instead of first tab i would like to activate second tab.

Comment: Could you share the jQuery code you've tried so far?

Comment: i think you can do nothing while page reloads

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remember which tab was active after refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299435/remember-which-tab-was-active-after-refresh)

Comment: `active` is class which contain some `css` to high light your tab if you don't want to add `active` class then you need to add all those `css` in `Jquery` to your tab

Comment: I mean, no need to use "active" class in any tags. We may use "active" class in JQuery code.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to open always tab-2 trigger works after tab initialize.

```
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
$('#tabs').find('a[href="#tabs-2"]').trigger('click');
});
```

[If you want to hold the last stage of tab see this old so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299435/remember-which-tab-was-active-after-refresh)

Comment: Shree, i unable to get the Jquery in your shared link. Please provide full jquery code for my HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can use option and set active tab using 0 based index like this. So in the below example i use to index 2 to activate third tab.

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 2 );
```

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 2 );
  } );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

ul.tab {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.tab li {float: left;}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.tab li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.tab li a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
ul.tab li a:focus, .active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
</style>
<body>

<p>Click on the links inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<ul class="tab">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
     
</body>
</html>
```